# listen to radio on xperia ray with wireless headset

Tags: headset, fm-radio

Does anyone know how I can still listen to the radio on my Xperia ray even with my Novero Rockaway Stereo Bluetooth Headset. I tried inserting a handsfree while connected to the bluetooth headset but it ignores the bluetooth handset alltogether and if there is no wired headset the radio won't start.
I know I can listen to online radio but I don't want that I want FM.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of phones (including Xperia series) does not have an internal FM radio antenna, so they need a wired headset to be inserted, in order to use its wire as antenna.

You cannot use FM radio until you plug a wired headset to the phone.

Comment: Can't I get something like an antenna to plug in but still hear the radio in the wireless headset?